# Error code when migrate

Tags: plugin-development, database, widgets, errors, server

I got this error code after migration to different server.

> Warning:
> require_once(/home/customer/www/noname.com/public_html/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/customer/www/noname.com/public_html/wp-includes/default-widgets.php
> on line 11
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/home/customer/www/noname.com/public_html/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/local/php74/pear') in
> /home/customer/www/noname.com/public_html/wp-includes/default-widgets.php
> on line 11

I delete the complete php file from ftp just to see the reaction but same error apears. I null it in DB and it still remains.

Any clue? *(for the record noname.com have nothing to do with this just a name i use.

Comment: From the error message it's clear that there's files missing from the migration. It sounds like your solution was to delete more files? You need to recover those files. Do a manual update of WordPress: https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

Comment: the thing is that those files where there i deleted and replaced them again. And got those error still..however..one of sudden the site kicked in and worked for no actual reason..im clueless..

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that all required php extensions are installed on the new server?
you can compare it with the old server

the list if required PHP extensions for Wordpress from official Wordpress website:
https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/server-environment/